# Configuring MongoDB datasource in JBoss 7

Tags: java, mongodb, jboss7.x

Does anyone know how I can configure a MongoDB datasource in JBoss AS 7?

I'm guessing I can set up the Mongo driver as a module in JBoss in the same way as I have done previously with a MySQL driver, then add a dependency to this in the manifest of my EAR. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Sounds like something worth trying.  Should just be a JNDI connection pool to set up.  Give it a go and let us know how it works.

Comment: Yeah, no problem, I'll try it now and report back. I'm new to NoSQL so still getting to grips with parallels/differences.

Comment: Yep, seems to do the trick. I'll write a proper answer in case anyone else has the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation on this but it turns out to be pretty simple. Just download the [driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) and set it up as a module in JBoss like [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7).

Then add a dependency to the META-INF/MANFEST.MF file of your EAR. If you're using Maven you can add something like this to the configuration section of the EAR plugin in your pom.xml.

```
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>com.mongodb</Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
```

There doesn't seem to be any need to configure it as a data source. This is all I've done and I can see in the logs that the database is accepting connections.