# Configure a MongoDB datasource for connection pooling in JBoss

Tags: java, mongodb, jboss, connection-pooling

Would anyone be able to help me achieve connection pooling in Jboss by configuring a MongoDB datasource? I've already followed the steps in one of the threads here [Configuring MongoDB datasource in JBoss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535259/configuring-mongodb-datasource-in-jboss-7) but that doesn't explain precisely how I could achieve connection pooling.I'm using Jboss EAP 6.4.0.

Comment: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/94065240033/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-java-part-i Read very closely.

Comment: I can't see why using a MongoDB JDBC driver (http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php) would be different from any other jdbc driver (mysql, sybase,etc.)

Comment: @nnunes10- I've tried with 2 different datasources so far. One is teiid-8.13.1-jdbc.jar from here (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/teiid88final/MongoDB+Data+Sources) and the second is  mongo3.0.2.jar. Teiid-8.13.1-jdbc.jar is recognized as a legitimate driver by the jboss admin console but gives me this ( Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Wrong driver class [class org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidDriver] for this connection URL [jdbc:mongo://10.174.124.26:27017/bli]) when I run my app.The second jar is not recognized as a datasource. I also found this unity driver but it's not free.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg- thank you for the link. Needed your advice on this part of the document though:-
_the MongoClient is effectively the connection pool, so for every new MongoClient, you are opening a new pool. Using a single MongoClient (and optionally configuring its settings) will allow the driver to correctly manage your connections to the server._

Does this mean that I don't really need to bother about the pooling at the server level?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define your datasource in the jboss server.
In this case, you have to setup the driver for MongoDB. See the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_BRMS_Platform/5/html/BRMS_Administrator_Guide/Configuring_a_Datasource_for_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6.html).

Then you just need to add the element `<pool>` inside your `<datasource>` definition:

```
<pool>
   <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
   <max-pool-size>2</max-pool-size>
</pool>
```